# Modify a GeoServer source data object when you modify a GeoServer to OpenLayers object

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am currently looking for a way to modify the GeoServer original data if I modified the object on the map after floating the object stored in the GeoServer in the OpenLayers. Is there any way?

Code for receiving GeoServer data from the OpenLayers map.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/go',
    type : 'POST',
    success : (value) => {
            let wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:????/geoserver/testshp/wms',
            params: {
                'VERSION' : '1.1.0',
                'LAYERS': 'testshp:doorswindows',
                'FORMAT' : 'image/png',
                'TILED' : true,
            },
            serverType : 'geoserver',
            // crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
        })
        let map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [vWorldMap],
            overlays : [mapOverlay],
            view: mapView
        })
        let wmsMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
            visible : true,
            title : 'map',
            source : wmsSource
        })
       map.addLayer(wmsMap)
    },
    error : (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

example
[image]

To float the layer as OpenLayers, transform the layer, and then transform the deformed layer into GeoServer as well.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I do not really understand the question. But if you want to edit data on the server you first have to allow it in your GeoServer instance. Presumably with WFS-T or so